# Is it possible to inject service class in abstractview class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I'd like to use common function(@service class object) in abstract view class which is below.
I will make some views for my project, so I would like to make common function for convenience in ExcelSharedService class.
But it doesn't work well. 
Could you give me some advice ? please...

```java
public class ExcelView extends AbstractXlsxView {

    // this part won't be injected when this class is initiated.
    @Inject
    private ExcelSharedService excelSharedService;


    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Workbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        // create sheet
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Project");

        Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
        row.createCell(0).setCellValue("A");
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue("B");
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue("C");


       final String[] dataList = new String [] {"10", "20", "30"}; 
       CellRangeAddressList range = new CellRangeAddressList(1, 10000, 1, 1);

       // this is common function
       excelSharedService.setValidation(sheet, range, dataList);

    }
}
```

ExcelSharedService.java

```java
@Service
public class ExcelSharedService {

    public void setValidation(Sheet sheet, CellRangeAddressList range, String[] dataList) {
            DataValidationHelper helper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
            DataValidationConstraint constraint = helper.createExplicitListConstraint(dataList);
            DataValidation validation = helper.createValidation(constraint, range);
            sheet.addValidationData(validation);
    }


    public void setMergedRegion(Sheet sheet, CellRangeAddress range, String value) {
        sheet.addMergedRegion(range);
        Row row = sheet.createRow(range.getFirstRow());
        Cell cell = row.createCell(range.getFirstColumn());
        cell.setCellValue(value);
    }
```

Error Message Below

```
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractXlsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractXlsView.java:68)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at jp.co.nttdataccs.macau.web.trace.MdcPreparationFilter.doFilterInternal(MdcPreparationFilter.java:39)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at jp.co.nttdataccs.bmf.config.BmfCsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(BmfCsrfFilter.java:39)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I getting NullPointerException.

___
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at ExcelView.buildExcelDocument(PipeLineProjectUpdateExcelView.java:100)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractXlsView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractXlsView.java:68)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
___

Comment: Please edit the question and paste error there, also show us ExcelSharedService

Comment: thank you for your help.
I've added the error message & ExcelSharedService code.

Comment: so, why not you use `@Autowired`

Comment: It is preferable to use lombok library for DI in the project.
And even if I use @Autowired, I got same error...

Comment: `@Service` is a spring annotation. Lombok plays no roll in this. You will need to show how you configured the spring context. Also read up on [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-annotations-resource-inject-autowire)

Comment: right. I made a mistake above(not lombok but javax.inject.Inject).
thank you for your advice, I'll check this out.